# putting code in wordpress category page

Tags: wordpress, loops, ads, posts

I am using wordpress.
I am using double colums to show my posts.
I just think to show ads in between my 2 and 3 posts. e.g
post 1 | post2 
Ad will show here
Post3 | Post 4

But as my theme is looping 2 posts so when i am placing

```html
 <?php if ($count == 2) : ?>
Ad will show here
<?php endif; $count++; ?>
```

before php endwhile 
What i am getting is
post 1 | post2
Ad will show here | Ad will show here
Post3 | Post 4

My code is alos turned into two.

**It is solved now. i had same template part for showing recent posts in sidebar that's why it was showing two times.**
Regards

Comment: Where do you initiate `$count`? Where do you reset it back to zero? Can you share more code? :)

Comment: i add it as <?php $count = 1; ?>
        <?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>

Comment: **It is solved now. i was same template part for showing recent posts that's why it was changing into two**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php if ($count == 2) : ?>
Ad will show here
<?php  $count++; endif; ?>
```

This is not the exact code for you to copy and paste.
what i'm trying to show is that you are incrementing the $count variable after the endif; (actually don't know where that endif loop started) try to write more detailed code that you are using currently.

Comment: Infact my theme is using template part. so i have to put code on two different page. Kindly check full code of theses pages here.     [Primary Page](http://pastebin.com/W7B20TaK)   And  [2nd page](http://pastebin.com/00yqXEX0). Please tell me if you need any other page code

Comment: For the 2nd Page add <?php $count=1; ?> on line 39, there is not initialization of $count variable in that page

Comment: infat 1st page call 2nd page in it. by include command. i have to add $count in this case or not????

Comment: Also please tell me what code i have to add to show only 1 ad instead of 2?

Comment: **It is solved now. i was same template part for showing recent posts that's why it was changing into two**